# ipv6 migrating from ipv4 on local lan

Tags: ipv6

I started to migrate local lan from ipv4 to ipv6
I'm a little inexpert about this new ip,and for
be lazy I use those address,short and simple

Old ipv4 net

```
hpux1  192.168.0.13
hpux2  192.168.0.12
linux3 192.168.0.14
```

New ipv6 net

```
hpux1  fe80::1
hpux2  fe80::2
linux3 fe80::3
```

The question is the address fe80::* is reserved?
Or I can use on my localnet without problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IPv6, the `fe80::/10` range is the link-local address range. You cannot route using link-local addresses. All the link-local addresses on a single host will be in the same range, so you must scope the address so that your OS knows which interface to use.

With IPv6, you can assign multiple addresses on each interface, and each interface will have a link-local address, and you can have addresses in the Global range on the interface, too.

Comment: This address is good? fe80::ee03

Comment: Yes, for a link-local address. An IPv6 address is 128 bits long, and the link-local range only has 10 of those bits reserved for the Network ID. You have 64 bits for an Interface ID, and that is a huge number of hosts: `18,446,744,073,709,551,616`, which is `0000:0000:0000:0000` to `ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` in the Interface ID of an IPv6 address.

Comment: My interest is a ipv6 address for local lan,fe80:: is good or i have to use other prefix?

Comment: If you ever have multiple LAN segments or want to use the Internet, a link-local address will not work. It's like using APIPA (`169.254.0.0/16`) addressing for IPv4. You can use it only on the same link. Also, some applications can't handle using an IPv6 address with the scope ID (e.g. `%1` or `%eth0`) on the end of the address.